# Which Coxeter groups can be realized as affine reflection groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, euclidean-geometry

Every affine reflection group has a Coxeter presentation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_group#Relation_with_Coxeter_groups). How do you tell which Coxeter presentations arise from affine reflection groups in this way?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the Cartan matrix has to be positive semidefinit with kernel dimension 1.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group#Affine_Coxeter_groups